# Why is this XML producing a "...must be well-formed" validation error?

Tags: java, xml, jsp, servlets

I have a TLD (Tag Library Descriptor) file in my WEB-INF folder in my J2EE web project. I copied the TLD file from my textbook. In Eclipse EE, near the taglib line, it gives me the error:

> The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.

The XML/TLD file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

< taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
<tlib-version>1.2</tlib-version>
<uri>DiceFunctions</uri>
<function>
<name>rollIt</name>
<function-class>foo.DiceRoller</function-class>
<function-signature>
int rollDice()
</function-signature>
</function>
</taglib>
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @AnubianNoob - why is eclipse giving me the error. I am new to xml files. I even used w3c validator, but could not figure out the source of the error. I don't know why this got so many downvotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`< taglib ....>` Should be `<taglib .....>`

Notice the lack of space between the `<` and `taglib`.

Comment: oh okay. thanks. I am new to xml. I tried using w3c validator before I came here, but could not understand anything.

Comment: check http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.ASP, not the greatest tutorial but it should get you started, xml is rather simple.